# $k[x,y,z]$ and modules.

Tags: modules, polynomial-rings

My professor gave us this example on modules (he started this by saying what is a basis? what is the meaning of linearly independent?):

> $R = k[x,y,z]$ where $k$ is a field and $I = xyR + yz R + xz R$. Take $u = xy, v = yz, w = xz$. Then $I = uR + vR + wR.$ So, $$zu - xv = 0, xv - yw = 0, zu - yw = 0.$$ Hence $$\begin{bmatrix}
> z & -x & 0\\
> 0 & x & -y\\
> z & 0 & -y
> \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
> u \\
> v \\
> w
> \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\
> 0\\
> 0
> \end{bmatrix}, $$
>
> $\det A = 0.$
>
> The span of $u,v,w$ is $Ru + Rv + Rw = I$ so $I$ can not be spanned by $2$ elements.
>
> Upshot: $I \ncong_R R^2 = R(1,0) \oplus R(0,1)$

And I am for my life do not understand the idea my professor wanted to convey, could someone help me in trying to understand my professor's mind?

Comment: hi @mathmusic; welcome to math stackexchange! :) would you mind adding a bit more detail as to which part of the quoted paragraph is confusing you? at the moment it is not clear which part you need help with, so it's a bit difficult to answer your question

Comment: Hi @AtticusStonestrom I am understanding every detail in the example .....  but I am not understanding the big picture .... how is this an example of a module .... what idea my professor wanted to convey by giving us this example?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I think one of my questions is how do we get the equations $$z.u -x.v =0, ....$$?

Comment: @mathmusic, those equations follow directly from the definitions of $u,v,w$.

Comment: I think the point is something like: we'd like to think of the ideal $I$ as a vector space over $R$ (the way e.g. $\Bbb R^3$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$), but things aren't as well-behaved since $R$ is only a ring and not a field. In particular, $I$ is generated or "spanned" by this 3-element set, which seems to be minimal even though there are these "linear combinations" of $u,v,w$ that equal $0$.

Comment: @Karl how they follow?

Comment: $R$ is the [ring of polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Definition_(multivariate_case)) in the three variables $x,y,z$ with coefficients in $k$. $u$ is the polynomial $xy$ and $v$ is the polynomial $yz$, so $zu-xv=xyz-xyz=0$.

Comment: @Karl is my professor trying to give me an example of a module that is not free?

Comment: @Karl what is the point of saying that it can not be spanned by 2 elements?

Comment: And why my professor calculated the determinant?@Karl

Comment: I think this is just an example of how modules aren't as nice as vector spaces. In linear algebra, if $u,v,w$ are vectors that span a subspace $S$, and we have $au+bv=0$ for some elements $a,b$ of the underlying field, then $u,v$ are not linearly independent, so we can discard one of them and still have a spanning set. This works because we can divide through by $b$ to get $v=\frac abu$, showing that $v$ is "redundant". But if our scalars are a ring instead of a field, we don't have division, and we need to carefully reconsider the notions of linear independence, basis, dimension, etc.

Comment: @Karlwhat is the importance of showing that the determinant is zero?

Comment: I don't understand the point of that part.

Comment: maybe  my professor want to show by the determinant being zero that $x,y,z$ are linearly dependent?@Karl