# understanding the contradiction of $I$ is not free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

My professor gave us this example of a module that is not free :

> $R = k[x,y,z]$ where $k$ is a field. $I = xyR + yz R + xz R \subset R.$ Take $u = xy, v = yz, w = xz$ then $I = uR + vR + wR$, and so $$zu - xv = 0, xv - yw = 0, zu - yw = 0.$$

**Claim: I is not a free $R$-module.**

And she gave us the following

**Proof:**

" Assume by contradiction that $I$ is free. Let $S$ be an $R$-basis of $I.$ Choose $s_1, \dots , s_n \in S$ so that:

$$u = r_1s_1 + \dots + r_ns_n, v = r_1^{'}s_1 + \dots + r_n^{'}s_n.$$
Since $zu -xv = 0 = (zr_1 - xr_1^{'})s_1 + \dots + (zr_n - xr_n^{'})s_n$ then $zr_i - xr_i^{'} = 0\ \forall i$ which implies that $z \mid r_i^{'}, x\mid r_i$ (because $R$ is a UFD).

Now, write $r_i^{'} = a_i z, r_i = b_i x.$ Then $xy = u = \sum r_is_i = \sum b_i x s_i$ and so $y = \sum b_i s_i \in I$ which is a contradiction."

But I do not understand why she needed to use that $R$ is a UFD and I do not understand the contradiction. Is not $x,y,z$ are linearly dependent because we have   $$\begin{bmatrix}
z & -x & 0\\
0 & x & -y\\
z & 0 & -y
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
v \\
w
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}, $$

$\det A = 0.$

So what is wrong in writing $y$ as a linear combination of elements of the basis?

Could anyone clarify these points to me please?

Comment: As a side remark: To show that an ideal $I \subset R$ is not a free $R$-module, it suffices to show that $I$ is not principal. Indeed any two (distinct) elements $x, y \in I$ are linearly dependent since $$(-y)\cdot x + x\cdot y = 0.$$ So the only bases for $I$ are either the empty set or singletons.

Comment: So she showed here what @AryamanMaithani?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about linear independence and linear dependence in this example as you can see from my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043934/kx-y-z-and-modules @AryamanMaithani Isee that $x,y$ are already linearly dependent because $u = xy$